# Capture a group containing URL encoded

Tags: java, android, regex

I tried, searching this but I didn't find anything.

I found a regex pattern to extract username from facebook link:

```
(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?
```

The problem with this is that it can not capture the username if it is encoded. The original username is in arabic. For example, this kind of links:

https://www.facebook.com/%D9%82%D8%B1%D9%8A

The problem is with the percentages, but how to fix it? Please help me!

Comment: You want to first urldecode the string, then use unicode character classes in your regular expression. Ideally, however, you'd use a library built specifically for parsing URIs rather than a regex. What language or programming environment are you using?

Comment: @mwp I am using Java, Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mwp I resolved the problem by just decoding the URL before passing it to the matcher.

```
link = URLDecoder.decode(link.replaceAll("/$", ""), "UTF-8");
```

`replaceAll()` is to remove any trailing slashes.